# iPad tab bar app not autorotating

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitabbarcontroller

I made a tab bar application, but it will not rotate into landscape.

I have the 'shouldAutoRotate' set to "return YES" but that doesn't work... Any suggestions?

Comment: Is the rotation lock on?

Answer (score 3):

All of the view controllers in the tab bar controller need to return YES for landscape in order for it to rotate.

Answer (score 0):

I also think so because when app launches all the view controller's 'shouldAutoRotate' getting fired..

Answer (score 0):

What happened in my app I was using off the shelf UITabBarController which I dragged over in xCode interface builder. It did not rotate itself (I guess by defauls it just displays portrait).

Solution was to create a new class (with right click on the file list) New File > Objective C Class > and then in "Subclass of:" type UITabBarController, and give it a meaningful name (like MyUITabBarControllerInHorisontalOrientation)

What happened you created a file which has all the functions of UITabBarController, but also you can add few more to it. So you need to add in .m file a function like this:

```
  - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
   {
          Boolean ans = (UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft == interfaceOrientation);
          //this will display tabbar as a landscape left, 
          // but you can add more orientations using && operator
          return ans;
   }
```

and then in interface builder (the wysiwyg interface where you drag and drop buttons) click your UITabBarController you dragged over and in Utilities > Identity Inspector > Custom class (often visible as a right hand side panel) chose your MyUITabBarControllerInHorisontalOrientation.

I hope it helps